# Googlecharts arraytodatatable possible dimension issue?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a 2 arrays which I got from php, put into a single 2D Javascript array. I'm trying to use it to autofill a Google Chart DataTable, but so far I've had no success.
The only thing that I can think of is that maybe the array ix MxN dimension, while the function needs a NxM array?

Either does it not work because the first array is made of numbers?

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Pressure Monitor</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var samptable = new Array();
    samptable[0] = new Array(2);
    samptable[0,0]= nbsamples;  //first array obtained from php
    samptable[0,1]= samples;   //second array obtained from php. both are merged into a 2d array
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    //var data; 
    function drawVisualization() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(samptable[0]);
  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data, {curveType: "function",
                  width: 500, height: 400,
                  vAxis: {maxValue: 10}}
          );
    }
    //function draw(){

    //}
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>

</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
<div id="visualization" style="width: 800px; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code used to get nbsamples and samples:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'var samples = new Array("', join($ydata,'","'), '");';
echo 'var nbsamples = new Array("', join($nbsamples,'","'), '");';
echo '</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead to create the arrays:

```
var samptable = [];
samptable.push(nbsamples);
samptable.push(samples);
```

Then, since it appears that your arrays are all data, make sure to specify *opt_firstRowIsData* option as true (defaults to false):

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(samptable, true);
```

You might want to also verify that *nbsamples* and *samples* are valid arrays by logging them to the console:

```
console.log(nbsamples);
console.log(samples);
```

For this to be valid, they should each appear as a row of data (same number of items), eg:

```
[5, 4, 10]
[1, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Hello! Sorry for the late reply! I've tried your method, and its working halfway. Right now it's actually showing me an error, instead of nothing at all. It's saying that "Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string" even though the data is a number!

I'll put the code I use to get the two arrays in the question above.

Also the console is not showing the arrays, just saying that they are not defined, even though I can see them if I try to output them in the alert().